# Cocos2d on iPhone: Using Sprites Defined in Separate Class Files

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to draw two sprites on the same screen. I have defined the two sprite objects in two separate class files.

1. If I comment out two lines (see "item 1" comment below) then I get a display as [a backgroundimage[background2.jpg] with a sprite[grossini.png] on the left side.
2. If I uncomment the two lines I do not get the background image and sprite of (gameScreen.m). I get only the sprite [grossinis_sister1.png] defined in (enemy.m).
3. But what I need is a [backgroundimage[background2.jpg]], sprite[grossini.png] and sprite [grossinis_sister1.png] in one screen.

This is  implementation file of my first class:

```
#import "gameScreen.h"

#import "enemy.h"
@implementation gameScreen

-(id)init
{
    if((self = [super init]))
    {
        CCSprite *backGroundImage = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"background2.jpg"];
        backGroundImage.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
        CCParallaxNode *voidNode = [CCParallaxNode node];
        [voidNode addChild:backGroundImage z:-1 parallaxRatio:ccp(0.0f,0.0f) positionOffset:CGPointZero];   

        [self addChild:voidNode];

        CGSize windowSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

        CCSprite *player = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"grossini.png"];
        player.position = ccp(player.contentSize.width/2, windowSize.height/2);

        [self addChild:player z:0];
        //eSprite = [[enemy alloc]init]; //<-- see item 1             
        //[self addChild:eSprite];      
    }

    return self;
}
```

This is my implementation file of my second class:

```
#import "enemy.h"

#import "gameScreen.h"
@implementation enemy
-(id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        CGSize windowSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

        CCSprite *enemySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"grossinis_sister1.png" ];
        enemySprite.position = ccp(windowSize.width/2, windowSize.height/2);

        [self addChild:enemySprite];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: It seems like you have some conceptual misunderstandings of how to structure an iPhone application. Google "iPhone game tutorial" and I'm sure you'll find something at your level which will show you the right way to do things. Also, your question is posed so vaguely that there's no way to provide a solution since you offer no code examples or even an idea of what classes you are using.

Comment: sorry I will edit my question in clear way.
thank you.

Comment: If you meant to include image links they did not come through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The high level understanding you need is this. A screen contains 1 or many layers a layer contains sprites.

So create a screen and then add a layer to it and add the sprites to the layer you created.  Of course one can have many screens and a screen can consists of many layers.  But in a simple demo game create 1 screen, 1 layer, and add sprites to that layer.

See this link for more detail http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:basic_concepts.

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with Cocos2d but the normal pattern is to have a object that would own both gamescreen and enemy sprites and manage both.